# Rebinding and copying allocator from standard container

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, allocator

#### Background:

I wanted to create a function which, when given a `vector` V, returns a `vector` of `reference_wrapper`s VR to each element in V.

This is trivial, but I also wanted the returned vector to *copy the rebound allocator*, in case the original vector has a (possibly stateful) custom allocator.

I came up with the MVCE below, which compiles on godbolt.

#### Question:

- Is my understanding and implementation correct, specifically around the rebinding of the allocator?
- Will it work for all conforming user-defined allocators?
- If not, what have I missed?

#### Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

// A class to make my nasty string unmoveable, and therefore expensive
// to sort
struct Nasty
{
    Nasty(std::string s) : value_(std::move(s)) {}
    Nasty(Nasty const&) = default;
    Nasty& operator=(Nasty const&) = default;
    
    auto value() const -> std::string const& {
        return value_;
    }
    std::string value_;
};

// function object class to deduce types and perform the conversion
template<class V>
struct as_references_op
{
    using vector_type = V;
    using value_type = typename V::value_type;
    static constexpr bool is_const = std::is_const<vector_type>::value;
    using referred_type = std::conditional_t<is_const, std::add_const_t<value_type>, value_type>;

    using allocator_type = typename V::allocator_type;
    using a_traits = std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>;
    using rebound_allocator = typename a_traits::template rebind_traits<referred_type>::allocator_type;

    using result_type = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<referred_type>, rebound_allocator>;

    result_type operator()(V& v) const
    {
        auto result = result_type(v.begin(), v.end(), v.get_allocator());
        return result;
    }
};

// interface functions    
template<class T, class A>
decltype(auto) as_references(std::vector<T, A> const& v)
{
    auto op = as_references_op<std::vector<T, A> const>();
    return op(v);
}

template<class T, class A>
decltype(auto) as_references(std::vector<T, A>& v)
{
    auto op = as_references_op<std::vector<T, A>>();
    return op(v);
}

// test    
int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<Nasty> { Nasty("gah"), Nasty("bar"), Nasty("zoo"), Nasty("foo") };

    auto sv = as_references(v);

    auto by_dereferenced_value = [] (auto&& x, auto&& y) {
        return x.get().value() < y.get().value();
    };
    std::sort(begin(sv), end(sv), by_dereferenced_value);
}
```

Comment: This feels more like code review

Comment: @passerby not really. What I'm asking is for confirmation that I have understood the standard correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is permitted to convert a container's allocator to a rebound allocator type (e.g. for use in constructing a new container). However, for a type to meet the Cpp17Allocator requirements, it is only required that such conversion be possible through direct-initialization. As such, the new vector would need to be constructed like so:

```
auto result = result_type(v.begin(), v.end(), rebound_allocator(v.get_allocator()));
```

See [[allocator.requirements.general]/69](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements.general#69).

There is a subtlety here: [allocator.requirements.general]/69 holds only if `rebound_allocator` is a valid type, which it might not be (see [[allocator.requirements.general]/96](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements.general#96)). On the other hand, if the user expects to be able to use their allocator type with a standard library container template such as `std::vector`, then they generally should ensure that their allocator can be rebound to an arbitrary value type; see [[container.requirements.pre]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.pre#3) (implying that a rebound allocator may be used for construction and destruction) and [[container.reqmts]/64](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.reqmts#64) (implying that a rebound allocator may need to be used for allocation and deallocation). Because the standard provides no guarantees as to what the container's "internal type" might be, a user-defined allocator that can only be rebound to certain value types cannot portably be used with standard library containers. Consequently, it is reasonable for you to expect that converting an allocator obtained from a specialization of `std::vector` into a rebound type, and using that rebound allocator for allocation, construction, destruction, and deallocation, will work regardless of what value type you are rebinding to.